# How to chain couple OpenVPN servers?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have two different servers which both are OpenVPN server. I setup openvpn server with https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install script.

I want to chain them together, so the OVPNServerA connects to OVPNServerB.

So when I connect to ServerA, I have access to the internet with the network of ServerB.

Me <=> ServerA <=> ServerB

Note: I don't want the client do anything like `ssh`. In the client I want just to connect to openvpn to ServerA.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,,
OpenVPN Settings > Server under Apps.
Select the Exported Networks sub-tab from the Server tab.
By default, the internal interface network is included.
Make the client configuration next.
To include a new client, click Add
Choose Network under Type

Comment: This has nothing to do with the actual question.